# Grub background messed after installing a new Graphics card

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, grub2

I had a **nVidia Geforce 6200 128mb** AGP Vga card before and ubuntu was working fine and I had customized my Grub boot menu background, Today I installed a new graphics card which is  same as above but it is **256MB**, now the graphics of the grub menu is lowered (low resolution and color depth), what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Determine Resolution to Use

First determine the video resolution you are able to use. Go to the grub menu and enter `c` to get a "grub" prompt. Then enter:

```
set pager=more
vbeinfo
```

and copy down the resolution you want to use. I suggest that you use the preferred mode listed at the end,
if any.

You could also use `xrandr` to find your current mode. xrandr lists all modes and highlights the one in use.

will list your resolutions and highlight the one you are using.

---

### Alter Grub Configuration

In the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfwVWU84cnQ) Cako found yooyoomine suggests the following steps:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line containing `# GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600`

Edit the line, removing the initial "#" so it is no longer a comment, and change the resolution to the one you picked above. Save the file when done.

Now enter:

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

search for the following fragment (about half way down the file):

```
    cat << EOF
if loadfont `make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "${GRUB_FONT_PATH}"` ; then
  set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
```

----->

```
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
EOF
```

Where the line is enter the line:

```
set gfxpayload=keep
```

and save this file.

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then boot and test. If this disallows the normal use of grub you will have to either boot without seeing the menu, or use an Ubuntu Live CD, to unmake the changes.

Comment: sorry, not working , it's grub 1.9, is there a new version?

Comment: I'm on 12.04 and package grub common on my system is version 1.99-21ubuntu3.1. I don't have the problem so I wasn't able to try it myself. Sorry it didn't work for you.

Comment: no bro, it's the same, but it seems something else is not working correctly, after trying 100 of guides, I had enough, so I switched back to my old good looking graphics card and wow, seems great now... sorry for trouble... thank you for helping...I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

This cause is for the bad nvidia driver.I had the same problem before saw this video:
[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfwVWU84cnQ)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.