# windows 7 booting in background but shows the grub screen of UBUNTU 14.04 wallpaper in distorted way

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I dual booted my HP Pavilion 15-n012tx (which was pre-installed with Windows 8 pro) to Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.
Booting them was fine with no errors. Installed Windows and Ubuntu in separate partitions and updated my grub to show entries of Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Problem: whenever I select Windows 7 entry in Grub after a shutdown, it gets stuck at a pink/violet (I don’t know the exact colour but its the grub colour in a distorted way) screen, but Windows 7 loads in the background, as I am able to hear the Windows 7 start-up sound.

The same happened while dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. I couldn't find a solution to it, so went on for Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

config files:

- [`/etc/default/grub`](http://pastie.org/9989435)
- [`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`](http://pastie.org/9989437)
- [`lspci -nnk`](http://pastie.org/9989440)
- [`lsblk -f`](http://pastie.org/9989442)

[image]

Comment: i am not having a reputation of +10 so askubuntu.com is not letting me to post images. so sending you the link -
1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6klvkfmbgdqirn/20150228_154418.jpg?dl=0

Comment: /etc/default/grub - http://pastie.org/9989435
/boot/grub/grub.cfg - http://pastie.org/9989437
lspci -nnk - http://pastie.org/9989440
lsblk -f  - http://pastie.org/9989442

please have a look at this..

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/q/174571/175814

Comment: Very funny issue here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same problem with Dell Inspiron 15 3542 with Intel HD 4400 graphics.

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
```

Enabling the above line in `/etc/default/grub` solves the problem but disables the graphical grub and presents a basic text based Grub screen.

Mismatch in the resolution of graphical grub and windows boot screen appears to be the cause of the problem.

To enable graphical grub

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Comment the line:

```
# GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
```

Uncomment the line:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
```

This changes the grub graphical boot screen resolution to `1024x768`. Apply changes to grub:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

I tried the following resolutions on my system:

```
640x480 - not garbled, but windows boot graphics is not displayed
800x600 - garbled at times
1024x768 - works
1366x768 - garbled
```

The `1024x768` worked well for my system. Experiment with the resolutions and find one suitable for your system. Carry out various boot checks like restarting the system from linux to windows, windows to windows, windows to linux and power-on to boot windows.

Comment: Thanks I was experiencing the same problem and your method works. Is there a method to determine the resolution that the Windows 7 boot screen uses before the system actually loads the drivers for the hardware?

Comment: was 640x480 for the user case I bumped into...

Answer (score 8):

You could try to disable the graphical grub spash.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` (as root) and uncomment

```
#    GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
```

(remove the #)

after that, run `sudo update-grub` and see if it helped.

Comment: IS this thing happening because i did not install any drivers of windows 7?

Comment: Not sure. Usually windows should display a picture regardless of installed drivers or if grub is running before. But you certainly could try installing windows drivers. Or you could try to set GRUB to terminal mode as I suggested above.

Comment: Yeah! it worked i guess! Booted 3 4 times Ubuntu then windows and then windows then ubuntu..Till now, no problem!
**THANK YOU SO MUCH** _peace_

Answer (score 1):

FOR GUI USERS:

1. INSTALL grub-customizer.
2. Goto General settings->advanced settings
3. check (GRUB_TERMINAL -> console) in advanced settings.
4. Try different resolution in Appearance settings.
   check custom resolution -> Try first 640x480