# dual boot problem (windows doesn't boot )

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I installed windows 7 on thinkpad E440 and it worked correctly then I installed ubuntu 16.04 and it worked correctly too. I switched between them a couple of times and everything was ok. after a couple of hours ubuntu worked correctly but when I wanted to boot into windows, when I choose windows loader in the grub I face with ubuntu purple screen and it stucks there nothing happens like the below image . I tested win 10 and 7 alongside ubuntu both results was the same like told. I had win 8.1 on my laptop before starting to install Ubuntu but I formatted the whole disk and replaced it with zeroes. does anyone know how to fix this ? [image]
[image]

Comment: If system was originally Windows 8, then system is UEFI. But most users install Windows 7 in BIOS mode as that is default with DVD. You have to use flash drive to install in UEFI mode. So what is installed now? and in what mode? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that does not need chkdsk nor is hibernated. And Windows 8 or later is always hibernated, you must turn off fast start up in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I found the solution here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/590989/windows-7-booting-in-background-but-shows-the-grub-screen-of-ubuntu-14-04-wallpa :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows 7 booting in background but shows the grub screen of UBUNTU 14.04 wallpaper in distorted way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590989/windows-7-booting-in-background-but-shows-the-grub-screen-of-ubuntu-14-04-wallpa)